# Which is the closest train station?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## Goal

Write a full program that generates a map showing the local train stations and which train station is the closest to every point on the map.

## Requirements

### Input

A set of tuples.  The first is the (Width,Height) dimensions of the map.  The following tuples are the (X,Y) coordinates of each train station.  Coordinates are 0-based (ie the top-left corner of the map is `(0,0)`)  The input may be taken in any reasonable format (string, int array, tuple array, etc.)

Assume:

- The map has a positive width and height.
- All train stations are inside the map.
- There are between 1 and 26 train stations, inclusive.

### Output

Write a rectangular output to the console.

The first train station is designated `A`, the second `B` and so on.  Train stations should be shown with their upper-case letter.

Every other cell contains the lower-case letter of the closest train station.  Where there is a draw, travel to the station with the earliest letter (ie. choose B over C if they have a draw.)

Distance is measured in [taxi-cab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry): Δx + Δy

## Example

### Input

```
6,4 1,0 4,1 3,3
```

### Output

```
aAaabb
aaabBb
aaccbb
cccCcc
```

## Scoring

After one week, the source code in the least bytes wins.

Comment: @steveverrill No it was using the Manhattan distance too.

Comment: @flawr, agreed.  I would never have thought to search for that term.  I'll close this.